# SQL parameters asp.net(vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, parameters

Sorry for my bad English.I have a problem in my code:

```
Dim sq As String = "SELECT username FROM standing WHERE username = @user"
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(Sql.ConnectionString)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sq, con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            cmd.Parameters("@user").Value = "contesttest"
            con.Open()
            Dim index As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            con.Close()
            If (index > 0) Then
                'Something..
            Else
                'Something else..
            End If
```

in my code,"contesttest" is exists in Database and returnedrows(index) should be greater than 0.But index is **-1** !What's the problem?
my connectionstring is right.

It does not matter if C# or VB.Net

Comment: You don't need `c#` tag for this question. Deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your username field is an unique index (meaning that you don't have two username with the same value) then your query could be rewritten without using a SqlDataReader

```
Dim sq As String = "SELECT username FROM standing WHERE username = @user"
Using con SqlConnection(Sql.ConnectionString)
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sq, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@user").Value = "contesttest"
    con.Open()
    Dim username = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    If userName IsNot Nothing Then
        'Something..
    Else
       'Something else..
    End If
End Using
End Using
```

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) return the first column of the first row retrieved by your command. In the case you column is a unique index/primary key then you have just one row and you return just the username. So if there is something returned then you have found your user

Answer (score 1):

From [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> **For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command.** When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1.** If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

This is not a problem. It is a definition of `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Reader of some sort (like a SqlDataReader) to get the number of rows returned from a `SELECT` statement or `ExecuteScalar` to get a single returned value. Using `ExecuteNonQuery` will only return the number of rows affected when used with a `SELECT` statement.

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

- Read about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

i guess `SqlDbType.VarChar` will allow only one character ..you need to pass `length` also for varchar.

for Example:-

```
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar,80)
```

Comment: I am not sure about VB but in C#, you need to pass length also for varchar parameter, otherwise it will take only first character..